# How do I set individual background colours for each xtick

Tags: python, matplotlib, background

I have the code below to create a swarm plot using `seaborn`.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
data = {'Days': np.full((48, 5), [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]).reshape(-1),
        'Group': np.full((80, 3), ["Group1", "Group2", "Group3"]).reshape(-1), 
        'Value': np.random.rand(240)}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10), dpi=80)
sns.stripplot(x=df.Days, y=df.Value, jitter=0, size=5, ax=ax, linewidth=1,
              dodge=True, hue=df.Group, palette="Set1", data=df)
plt.show()
```

How can I change the background colour of the individual groups, int this case the different Days? So Day 4 has a grey Background, Day 7 a white, Day 8 grey again and so on? See in the image below.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `axvspan()` to do this. Below is the updated code. This will set every alternate xtick range as gray or white..

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
data = {'Days': np.full((48, 5), [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]).reshape(-1),
        'Group': np.full((80, 3), ["Group1", "Group2", "Group3"]).reshape(-1), 
        'Value': np.random.rand(240)}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10), dpi=80)
sns.stripplot(x=df.Days, y=df.Value, jitter=0, size=5, ax=ax, linewidth=1,
              dodge=True, hue=df.Group, palette="Set1", data=df)
for i in range(6):
    if i%2 == 0:
        plt.axvspan(i-0.5, i+.5, facecolor='gray', alpha=0.3)
plt.show()
```

[image]